# To put Solutionwide settings-file in Solution-Root with a Project-Template

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

I've a problm where I can't seem to find (or I use the wrong search terms) the answer to.

**My Problem:**
I want to create a Project-Template in VisualStudio (2013) which also have to put a settings-file (*.jcsettings.xml-File for JustCode-Solution-Settings) into the Solution-Root-directory (where the *.sln-file resides in)

I've tried to put a "..\" into the TargetFileName but this seems to be not allowed. Also a ProjectItem only gets copied if I'll declare it in the *.csproj-File. Is this a expected behavoir?

**My Question:**
If and how is this doable without writing your own IWizard and if you have to do it with IWizard can you give me some pointers on how to do it with IWizard?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Project Template can only influence the project itself directly, you will indeed need to implement the IWizard interface and interact with Visual Studio through the EnvDTE object to directly influence the Solution.